# XML Script Tag | PHP SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

I having been trying to find an explanation to no avail, but can anyone suggest why there is a script tag in XML and can this be removed using `PHPs SimpleXMLElement`.

If we see the image below the second tag is a self closing script tage `<script/>`.

[image]

Below are a number of other examples of this tag appearing. When I am creating my own XML using `SimpleXMLElement` I notice I too get this tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml

Can anyone tell me why this is included and is there any way to remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Below are a number of other examples of this tag appearing.

No, those files do not contain that tag. Download and inspect them using something other than your default browser. Likely you have some browser extension which injects a script into any and all pages.

Comment: This is absolutely the answer. Should have downloaded one and checked. Many thanks